# Arbitrary acceleration written as centripetal acceleration of approximating circle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile

Suppose I want to find the acceleration of a projectile given its trajectory, i.e. its space coordinates as functions of time.

I have heard that the acceleration can always be written as the centripetal acceleration of the circle approximating the motion, but I do not understand this quantitatively.

Can someone explain this correspondence?

Comment: I think there's actually a good question underneath here, it just suffers from poor written construction. Let's try to fix it up.

Comment: *I have heard that the acceleration can always be written as the centripetal acceleration of the circle approximating the motion* Do you have a reference for this statement (e.g., author & title)? Or maybe a diagram? I *think* I know what you're saying, but I'm not entirely sure & would appreciate clarification.

Comment: What Aneek recalls it incomplete. It should be clear that an acceleration (anti-)parallel to velocity is not described by *any* instantaneous circle and nearly as clear that any acceleration transverse to the velocity can be. Not that this is much use in finding trajectories as the information needed is identical to that needed to simply describe the accelerations in the first place.

Comment: @dmckee isn't it the case that the acceleration vector is the sum of a parallel component and another component which *can* be thought of as a centripetal acceleration?

Comment: @Daniel Sure. But Aneek seems to have overgeneralized.

Comment: @dmckee: Just trying to generate the facts :-)

Comment: I have got it, first we calculate the radius of the approximating circle by the formula of radius of curvatute... Radius of curvature and then use the formula $ v^2/r $

Comment: @daniel I'm a class 11 student, not like the professors around here, so expect a little lagging detailed description from me

Answer (score 0):

For an object on some trajectory the acceleration is defined by the usual equation:

$$ \mathbf{a} = \frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt} $$

where both $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are vectors, so this is a vector equation. Any trajectory can be locally approximated by its [osculating circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle), and the acceleration will then have the magnitude $v^2/r$, where $r$ is the radius of this circle, and it will be directed towards the centre of the circle.

Whether this is useful depends on the details of the trajectory. Although it applies to any trajectory, you replace the problem of calculating the acceleration directly with the problem of calculating the osculating circle, and both the position and radius of the circle will be functions of time. It's not obvious why calculating the osculating circle would be easier.